# How to match and merge two dataframes having completely different values except a single word? Have ABC with 10 rows and XYZ with 22550 rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have ABC with 10 rows and XYZ with 22550 rows.

dataframe ABC of values:

```
        0                        1           2
0   sun is rising         |  UNKNOWN    | 1465465
1   micheal has arrived   |   UNKNOWN   | 324654
2   goal has been scored | UNKNOWN     | 547854
```

and other XYZ of value

```
    0         1 
0 sun       | password1
1 goal      | password2

....
....
.....
....
22550
22551  micheal   | password3
```

how to map XYZ with (sun,goal and micheal) ABC and so that  1 with password would replace UNKNOWN 1 in ABC

output i need

```
    0                        1           2
0  sun is rising         |  password1    | 1465465
1   micheal has arrived  |   password3   | 324654
2   goal has been scored| password2     | 547854
```

tried below and getting respective errors:

```
d = dict(zip(XYZ[0],XYZ[1]))

pat = (r'({})'.format('|'.join(d.keys())))
ABC[1]=ABC[0].str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(d)
print(ABC)
```

error :TypeError: sequence item 16069: expected str instance, float found

```
from itertools import chain
abc.loc[:,1] = list(chain(*[xyz.loc[abc[0].str.contains(i),1] for i in xyz[0]]))
```

error: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

```
d = dict(zip(XYZ[0], XYZ[1]))
ABC[1] = [next(d.get(y) for y in x.split() if y in d) for x in ABC[0]]
print (ABC)
```

error:StopIteration:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get default parameter `no match` if not matching value:

```
d = dict(zip(XYZ[0].str.lower(), XYZ[1]))
ABC[1] = [next(iter(d.get(y) for y in x.lower().split() if y in d),'no match') for x in ABC[0]]
```

General solution:

```
import re

XYZ = XYZ.dropna()
d = dict(zip(XYZ[0].str.lower(), XYZ[1]))
for k, v in d.items():
    ABC.loc[ABC[0].str.contains(re.escape(k), case=False, na=False), 1] = v
```

Comment: I'm getting no matches . Is it because of lower and upper caps or spacing issues.Ex: ABC has  iphone xs  and XYZ has IPhone X S

Comment: @hukkemaaru - I guess some data problem, not some whitespaces? Check `print (XYZ[0].tolist())`. Also possible data not match, because not exist in `ABC` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187915/discussion-between-hukkemaaru-and-jezrael).